# change the same numbers in a matrix recursively

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, tail-recursion

given a matrix of int numbers, a row and col indexs (for a random cell that contains a number) and a new number, I need to recursively return the matrix- however now with all of the surrounding cells that matched the random cell number to the new one.  for example:
for the following matrix-

```
             4,1,2,2
             4,4,3,1
             1,4,4,4
             1,4,0,2
```

called by fill(grid,1,1,0),
this one needs to be returned:

```
 * 0    1   2   2
   0    0   3   1
   1    0   0   0
   1    0   0   2
```

what I tried is the following

```
public static int[][] fill(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int needed ) {

    if (i<= grid.length - 1 && j<=grid[0].length - 1 && i>0 && j>0) {
    grid[i][j] = needed ;

    if(legal_Neighbor(grid,i,j, i+1,j))
        grid= fill(grid, i+1,j,needed );
    if(legal_Neighbor(grid,i,j, i,j+1))
        grid= fill(grid, i,j+1,needed );
    if(legal_Neighbor(grid,i,j, i,j-1))
        grid= fill(grid, i,j-1,needed );
    if(legal_Neighbor(grid,i,j, i-1, j))
        grid= fill(grid, i-1,j,needed );

    }
```

where legal_Neighbor is a function I'm calling that's checking if both cells have the same number and are next to each other

been stuck on this for a couple of days. would love for some help

Comment: According to your posted sample, the neighbour concept seems unsual, seems to me you are replacing every  item of the matrix matching the one pointed by provided coordinates, isn't it?

Comment: correct. if the number I need to change is '4', then I need to return a matrix where all the '4's there are next to eachother  were changed to the needed number

Comment: that means it's just a propagation of values. that's easy

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr for my first HW it was non recursively which was indeed easy. now though with the recursion involved I can't seem to get it right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to propagate the needed value to neighbors with equal value to origin.

the point here, is to make each node in the grid acts like a automaton, to pass the value to the neighbor if itself gets changed.

following is the code, but i left `boundaryCheck` blank:

```
static int[][] fill(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int needed) {
    if (!boundaryCheck()) throw new RuntimeException();
    int[][] clone = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
    //Clone matrix grid
    for (int k = 0; k < clone.length; k++) {
        clone[k] = grid[k].clone();
    }
    propagate(clone, i, j, needed, grid[i][j]);
    return clone;
}

static void propagate(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int needed, int target) {
    if (!boundaryCheck() || grid[i][j] != target || needed == target) return;
    grid[i][j] = needed;
    propagate(grid, i+1, j, needed, target);
    propagate(grid, i-1, j, needed, target);
    propagate(grid, i, j+1, needed, target);
    propagate(grid, i, j-1, needed, target);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not so easy as you think (and the one who voted up). For instance, in your function propagate, you propagate right. this one will propagate left (between others), this left one will propagate right, and this would happen until the infinite.

Comment: overwrite grid .... in function fill, you may clone matrix before `propagate(clone, ....)`

Comment: @vivoconunxino It is not true ....  because, `grid[i][j] != target` and `grid[i][j] = needed`, only is true when `needed==target`

Comment: try with (2 1 1 1, 1 1 2 1, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 1) and fill(grid,1,2,0).  propagate would never reach 0,0

Comment: @vivoconunxino target == 2, this is modified by grid[1][2]=0 (in `grid[i][j] = needed;`), following, it does four recursive calls and all with grid[i][j] == 1 != target (in `grid[i][j] != target`), then recursion ending

Comment: yup, and that is why you never reach pos (0,0) witch contain another 2 that the function will never change

Comment: @vivoconunxino yes, pos (0,0) should not change, result: (2 1 1 1, 1 1 0 1, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 1)

Comment: Ops, then I thought it would be harder than that, you're right mate. I guessed all the contained cells should be reviewed, now I see this must be some function for some kind of Minesweeper.

Comment: Yeah... Agreed with target==needed case, should have a check there. But other than this, it should be ok.